# R: set.seed produces the same result after seed removal

Tags: r, random-seed

**Background.** I want to generate random sequences within a **for** cycle in `R v.3.5.0`. To do this I use the code like bellow:

```
rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
some_list = list()
for (iter in 1:3) {
  set.seed(iter)
  some_list[[iter]] = sample(1:10)
}
some_list
```

This code returns me a list like this:

```
> some_list
[[1]]
 [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
[[2]]
 [1]  2  7  5 10  6  8  1  3  4  9
[[3]]
 [1]  2  8  4  3  9  6  1  5 10  7
```

After that I'm rerunning the same script, and expect to have the seed to be reset after running `rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())` within session, hence get different result.

But the reality is different - I receive exact the same list even after removal of `.Random.seed` from `globalenv()`.
Please, see the screen attached with exact sequence of commands:
[Sequence of commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVbjf.jpg)

I'm really confused by such behaviour of set.seed.

**My question is:**

1) Is such behaviour of set.seed normal?

2) How to reset seed if `rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())` do not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `iter` in the `set.seed` which is the same.  Do you expect ` set.seed(1);
sample(1:10)` to show a different value for each run

Comment: @akrun, yes, I expect different result after run of rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are aiming for random behaviour with the call to `rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())`, so why not just remove the `set.seed` from your code altogether?

```
rm(.Random.seed, envir=globalenv())
some_list = list()
for (iter in 1:3) {
  some_list[[iter]] = sample(1:10)
}
some_list
```

The above produces different results each time you run it. There is no need to have `set.seed` in our code.

Comment: it works OK if seed is removed. Thanks for your reply. But I don't understand why after removal of .Random.seed new seed with the same value returns the same result. Is the reason of this behavior in formula nature of set.seed?

Comment: In your example, you're removing the seed & then setting it as 1 in your first loop. The point of `set.seed` is to ensure reproducible results in random processes. `set.seed` is a pseudorandom number generator, pseudorandom means that given the same starting point (in this case 1), the same numbers will always be selected, however without knowledge of the seed the sequence of numbers from that point forward will appear random to an observer. This video explains `set.seed` well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAYzAZwufKI.

Answer (score -1):

I created workaround which based on usage of Sys.time() as a seed. Here is a code:

```
some_list = list()
for (iter in 1:3) {
  set.seed(as.numeric(Sys.time()))
  some_list[[iter]] = sample(1:10)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
some_list
```

But, neverthless, I needed to add `Sys.sleep(1)` because this solution does not work if operation in the cycle lasts less than 1 second.
I beleive that this is just workaround and the main question is still opened.

Comment: That's a really bad solution.  Use @efbbrown's suggested solution if you want random results each time.